# Why waiting a task returned from async method gets blocked?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, nancy

I'm working on a Nancy/ASP.Net project.  I've tried to use WebRequest to get data from other web service and I've implemented the request in an async function.  I find a problem that when I try to wait on a task returned from the function, it gets blocked indefinitely.  The simplified code looks like this..

```
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nancy;

public class TestModule : NancyModule{
    public TestModule() {
        Get["/"] = p => "Hello, world";
        Get["/async/"] = p => {
            var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost:13254/");

//          var responseTask = req.GetResponseAsync();  // this works!
            var responseTask = getResponse(req);   // this gets blocked!
            var waitSuccess = responseTask.Wait(10000);

            return waitSuccess ? "Yeah!" : "woooh!";
        };
    }
    async Task<HttpWebResponse> getResponse(HttpWebRequest request) {
        return (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
    }
}
```

The code uses NancyFx but it happens as well on vanilla ASP.Net page.  The service on localhost:13254 is working fine.  If I use the task directly returned from request's GetResponseAsync(), the code works fine, but If I wrap it in an async method, it just gets blocked.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with the code? :( I can change to use synchronous version but the async function works find in other self-hosting services... so I'd like to use the same code here too if possible..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I describe this deadlock behavior [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

To fix this, you can either use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere, or you can use synchronous methods. The *ideal* solution is to use `await` all the way and never use `Wait` or `Result`, but that may not be possible in your situation (it would only work if Nancy worked with `async` delegates, i.e., `Get["/async/"] = async p => { ... };`).

Comment: Thank you to point this out :D  I haven't tried Nancy Async yet so I have to live with this for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to solutions provided from Stephen, I resolve with just changing synchronization context at the root of Nancy route handler.  Given this utility function:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Utility.Async{
    static public class TPContext{
        static public T Call<T>(Func<T> handler) {
            var currentContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
            try {
                return handler();
            }finally {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(currentContext);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Just wrap the handler with this function

```
        Get["/async/"] = p => TPContext.Call(() => {
            var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost:13254/");

            var responseTask = getResponse(req);
            var waitSuccess = responseTask.Wait(10000);

            return waitSuccess ? "Yeah!" : "woooh!";
        });
```

and it just works ^^a  I don't think I need ASP.Net context.. and actually I hope Nancy'd make its own synchronization context since Nancy conceptually works differently from Asp.net already.