# HttpClient GetAsync ThreadPool Starvation

Tags: c#, async-await, threadpool, nancy, dotnet-httpclient

We have a microservice oriented backend stack. All of the microservices built top of `Nancy` and registered as windows services with `topshelf`.

One of the service, which handles most traffic (~5000 req/s), started to have threadpool starvation problem on 3 out of 8 servers.

This is the exception we are getting when hitting a specific endpoint:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingResponse(RequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartRequest(Object obj)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RandomNamedClient.<GetProductBySkuAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ProductService.<GetBySkuAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in ...\ProductService.cs:line 34
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ProductModule.<>c__DisplayClass15.<<.ctor>b__b>d__1d.MoveNext() in ...\ProductModule.cs:line 32
```

This endpoint calls another service -which is out of my team's domain- in order to get product data. Implementation of it as follows:

```
Get["/product/sku/{sku}", true] = async (parameters, ctx) =>
{
    string sku = parameters.sku;
    var product = await productService.GetBySkuAsync(sku);
    return Response.AsJson(new ProductRepresentation(product));
};
```

`ProductService.GetBySkuAsync(string sku)` implementation:

```
public async Task<Product> GetBySkuAsync(string sku)
{
    var productDto = await randomNamedClient.GetProductBySkuAsync(sku);
    if (productDto == null)
    {
        throw new ProductDtoNotFoundException("sku", sku);
    }

    var variantDto = productDto.VariantList.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Sku == sku);

    if (variantDto == null)
    {
        throw new ProductVariantDtoNotFoundException("sku", sku);
    }

    return MapVariantDtoToProduct(variantDto, productDto);
}
```

`RandomNamedClient.GetProductBySkuAsync(string sku)` implementation (it's from an internal package):

```
public async Task<ProductDto> GetProductBySkuAsync(string sku)
{
  HttpResponseMessage result = await this._serviceClient.GetAsync("Product?Sku=" + sku);
  return result == null || result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK ? (ProductDto) null : this.Decompress<ProductDto>(result);
}
```

`RandomNamedClient.Decompress<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)` implementation:

```
private T Decompress<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
  if (!response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
    return HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync<T>(response.Content).Result;
  using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream((Stream) new MemoryStream(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result), CompressionMode.Decompress))
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      int count;
      do
      {
        count = gzipStream.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
        if (count > 0)
          memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
      while (count > 0);
      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
    }
  }
}
```

All of our services built as Release/32-bit. We didn't tweak anything about threadpool usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest problem I see with this code is the `Decompress<T>` method which blocks on an async operations using `Task.Result`. This could, potentially, stall the retrieval of the thread currently processing the request to the threadpool, or even worse cause *deadlocks in your code* (this is exactly why you [shouldn't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)). I'm not sure if you've seen those requests get processed thoroughly, but if NancyFX is handling marshaling of the synchronization context for you (which seems like [it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001761/why-waiting-a-task-returned-from-async-method-gets-blocked)) that may very well be the root cause of the threadpools starvation.

You can alter this by making all the IO processing work inside that method `async` as well, and take advantage of the natural asynchronous API those classes already expose. Alternatively, and I definitely don't recommend doing this, you could use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere.

(*Side note* - you can simplify your code by using `Stream.CopyToAsync()`)

A proper async implementation would look like this:

```
private async Task<T> DecompressAsync<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    if (!response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();

    const int bufferSize = 8192;        
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(
                                   new MemoryStream(
                                        await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()), 
                                        CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await gzipStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, bufferSize);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. I was suspecting decompress was blocking us on execution. I will inform the team maintining the client library and i probably accept this as answer

Comment: @onatm Hope that helps!

Comment: @onatm Great to hear.